# Wiring 5 wires into one terminal end

Tags: bus, toggle-switch

I am putting a bank of 5 LED toggles on my boat.  I don't want to have 5 more terminal ends connected to my battery post.  Not sure how I should proceed on this.

Run all 5 wires back and then into one terminal end?
Run one wire up from the battery and then split it?

Thinking of putting in inline fuses on these toggles as well. Doubt that I will need them and they will just control lights and maybe a small pump.  Would it matter if I put the fuse before or after the toggle?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is a terminal end?

Comment: what are `LED toggles`? ... do you mean `illuminated switches`?

Comment: You all are kidding right?

Comment: There might be legal issues and/or insurance issues doing electrical wiring on your boat - you might want to consider that first. The placement and rating of the fuse(s) is critical as is the size of the conductors. So what you might think is simple and for someone who does this for a living it probably is, but if you get it wrong, then you can easily burn your boat along with yourself and your passengers.

Comment: Ask for advice in a store that sells boat supplies. This is really not a question about electronics engineering. Your solution depends on what kind of electrics you already have on board and if you have an open boat or a boat with a dry, protected space inside.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider a busbar- a copper or brass bar with a number of holes drilled along its length.  You’d typically terminate each wire with a ring or spade terminal and then secure each one with a screw.  You’ll want the same setup for positive and negative.  This does result in quite a lot of exposed ‘live’ metal so it’s wise to put the positive busbar (assuming you’re using negative ground) in a non-conducting box, and a fuse between the battery and the busbar.

Comment: So I would have 5 reds going into the box and then one coming out to the fuse-battery?  And then the same for the negative?  If that's the case, it is the simplest solution, but I just need to find a place to put the two bus bars in the best location.

Comment: Yes exactly.  You may be able to find an insulated communing block like this one:  https://nz.rs-online.com/web/p/distribution-blocks/8680792/

Comment: You may already be planning on it, but suggest you fill that block with grease or maybe even RTV - keep the moisture out.

Comment: I think a toggle box might be the best route to take